# Charging threshold set to 55 after each suspension

Tags: power-management, battery, battery-charging-threshold

a week ago I've reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my Asus TUF FA507XU in dual boot with Windows.

When I did so there was the Asus battery care tool active on Windows and I think something happened because after the installation the charge threshold set in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold` was set to 55.

I was able to change it using tlp but now each time I suspend my pc, the file is overwritten and the threshold set again to 55.

I have also checked in the bios and there does not seem to be any battery-related setting from which perhaps Ubuntu would take that threshold...